# Exit server terminal while after celery execution

Tags: django, celery, git-bash, celery-task, celerybeat

I have successfully created a periodic task which updates each minute, in a django app. I everything is running as expected, using `celery -A proj worker -B`.

I am aware that using  `celery -A proj worker -B` to execute the task is not advised, however, it seems to be the only way for the task to be run periodically.

I am logging on to the server using GitBash, after execution, I would like to exit GitBash with the celery tasks still being executed periodically.

When I press `ctrl+fn+shift` it is a cold worker exit, which stops execution completely (which is not desirable).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a linux server, You might want to use a process manager like supervisord or even systemd to keep your process running.

On windows, one might look at running celery as a service or running as part of rabbitMQ.

In WSL, it seems like a bat file will get wsl commands to run as a service.

Comment: I am on a linux server.. how would I use systems to keep the process running

Comment: You might look up "Daemonizing Celery with systemd". Systemd files tell the server to run an application and keep it running, and can give you a place to add parameters like where config files or log files should go.